# Defining $JAVA_HOME in mvn

Tags: java, shell, maven

My `mvn` script defined `JAVA_HOME` as follows:

```
 53 case "`uname`" in
 54   CYGWIN*) cygwin=true ;;
 55   MINGW*) mingw=true;;
 56   Darwin*) darwin=true
 57            if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ] ; then
 58              JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java/home
 59            fi
 60            ;;
 61 esac
```

As i understand it, the above will set `$JAVA_HOME` in event it is not set elsewhere.

Now .. how could this be that `$JAVA_HOME` is undefined if in `.zshrc`, i clearly

```
 34 JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java/home
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe, it needs an `export` in your .zshrc:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java/home
```

Comment: Indeed. I add JAVA_HOME to PATH and export that, but never export JAVA_HOME separately. Thank you Luigi

Comment: You just needed another pair of eyes :)

Comment: @mtk There is a 10 minute window until one can accept anything

Comment: @Jam yup.. didn't notice that. And also was about to mention you.Feeling sleepyyy..